# How can I extract variables from a R expression to be evaluated in data.frame context

Tags: r, regex, data.table, expression, pcre

I have expressions in `character` that are supposed to be evaluated in a `data.table` (not important just context).
To make sure all the required columns are present I would like to extract the said columns within the R expression.

***What I want:***

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(p001=rnorm(10),p002=rnorm(10),p003=rnorm(10))
expr <- 'p001+mean(p001,na.rm=TRUE)-weighted.mean(p002,w=p003)+someRandomOtherColumn'

# DT[,test:=p001+mean(p001,na.rm=TRUE)-weighted.mean(p002,w=p003)+someRandomOtherColumn]
# would fail as p004 is not in the columns
```

Basically I am looking for a way (probably a regex) that would extract from `expr` `p001,p002,p003,someRandomOtherColumn`.

***My view on it:***
The way I see it I should be able to capture `p001,p001,TRUE,p002,p003,someRandomOtherColumn` with some regex that would capture things within `f(,)` and then filter for 'allowed' column names (`TRUE` is not in that case).

Nested `f(,,)` are not an issue as I can call the same function recursively and nested `f(,(),)`are also fine.

***What I have:***
From now this is what I have, this can be made to work but this feels bad

```
expr <- 'p001+mean(p001,na.rm=TRUE)-weighted.mean(p002,w=p003)+someRandomOtherColumn'
clean <- function(string) gsub(string, pattern='[_|\\.|a-zA-z]+\\(([^)]*)\\)', replacement='\\1', perl=TRUE)
clean(expr)
[1] "p001+p001,na.rm=TRUE-p002,w=p003+someRandomOtherColumn"
# Then I can remove =* than split on ,|+|-|*
```

Comment: If you want to only get the values inside `f()`, `p004` should not be in the expected results. @Cath, I think `\\bp\\d+\\b` will overmatch in this case. There must be custom boundaries.

Comment: @statquant Can you guarantee there is no `(` and `)` inside the `f(...)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There can be nested `f()` but that's fine I can call the same function recursively

Comment: That complicates the problem. You may match nested `(...)`, but to match inside them, you will need a second pass.

Comment: What are "allowed" column names? I do not understand how `someRandomOtherColumn` is inside a `f()`.

Comment: I meant that TRUE for instance cannot be a variable name in R (or a data.frame column name), someRandomOtherColumn is not inside any f() sorry for the confusion, it is just there as any other column... anyway it looks like like @Sven got it we were on the wrong track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a `~` to your expression, you can create a valid R formula expression:

```
expr <- '~ p001+mean(p001,na.rm=TRUE)-weighted.mean(p002,w=p003)+someRandomOtherColumn'
```

This string can be converted to a formula with `as.formula`. Afterwards, the variable names can be extracted with `all.vars`:

```
all.vars(as.formula(expr))
# [1] "p001"             "p002"             "p003"             "someRandomOtherColumn"
```

Comment: LOL VERY SMART ! Hopefully I won't find a counter example

Comment: @statquant Thanks. Note that this approach is more robust than using regex since it makes use of R's expression parser.

Comment: Not sure why on earth I got downvoted... anyway thanks